# DateTimeFormatter of YYYY-ww resolves differently on mac and ubuntu

Tags: java, date, datetime-format

```
System.out.println(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-ww").withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(Instant.parse("2022-05-10T00:00:00.00Z"))
);
System.out.println(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-ww").withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(Instant.parse("2022-05-17T00:00:00.00Z"))
);
```

Why this pattern `YYYY-ww` resolves differently on Ubuntu and Mac:

**Ubuntu**: (default locale en_US, my computer)

```
2022-20
2022-21
```

**Mac:** (default locale en_GB)

```
2022-19
2022-20
```

**EDIT**

```
System.out.println(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-ww").withLocale(Locale.UK).withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(Instant.parse("2022-05-10T00:00:00.00Z"))
);
System.out.println(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-ww").withLocale(Locale.UK).withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(Instant.parse("2022-05-17T00:00:00.00Z"))
);
```

returns:

```
2022-19
2022-20
```

Still, the question is why pattern `ww` is Locale specific? I don't see that in documentation for https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html
or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: Are the two machines using the same Java version? I got the Ubuntu output on my mac book, with Java 17.

Comment: What's the Locale on each machine?

Comment: @Sweeper Hm. I got the "2022-19" output on my Mac (m1 air), with Java 17 (Zulu 17.28.13). Default Locale en_GB

Comment: @Michael Ah must be a locale/start of week problem then. I set the locale to `Locale.UK` and it output `2022-19`.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it's Locale problem, but when I supply locale to DateTimeFormatter with `.ofLocale()` it did not help

Comment: @ByeBye Please edit your question to include the default Locale from each machine (`Locale.getDefault()`).

Comment: `new Locale("en_GB")` is not the correct way to make a `Locale` object... Just do `Locale.UK`? I even wrote that in my comment...

Comment: The *entire* pattern is locale specific. See [`ofPattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withLocale-java.util.Locale-): "... The formatter will use the default FORMAT locale..."

Comment: *Still, the question is why pattern `ww` is Locale specific?* Which week number would you expect to have if not the week number of the formatter’s locale? Locales do not have the same week numbers, they don’t even begin a new week on the same day-of-week.

Comment: If I remember correctly, weeks start on Sundays in the US (and on Mondays in UK).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the US locale, the first week of the year can have one to seven days, whereas in the UK, the first week of the year needs to have at least 4 days.

```
WeekFields.of(Locale.UK).getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() // 4
WeekFields.of(Locale.US).getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() // 1
```

Also, a US week starts on a Sunday, whereas a UK week starts on a Monday.

This means that for the US, the first week of 2022 is the single Saturday of 2022-01-01, and 2022-01-02 is the start of the second week. On the other hand, for the UK, the first week of 2022 starts from 2022-01-03, since the first two days of the year don't form a week. And this is where that extra week for the US machine came about.

When creating a `DateTimeFormatter` using [`ofPattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withLocale-java.util.Locale-), the default formatting locale of the machine is used:

> The formatter will use the [default FORMAT locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault-java.util.Locale.Category-). This can be changed using `withLocale(Locale)` on the returned formatter

Hence the difference.

I suppose you want standard [ISO 8601 weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) here, and not want anything to do with locales. One way to do this is to construct a `DateTimeFormatter` using `IsoFields`:

```
var dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
  .  appendValue(IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR, 4)
    .appendLiteral('-')
    .appendValue(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, 2)
    .toFormatter().withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println(
    dtf.format(Instant.parse("2022-05-10T00:00:00.00Z"))
);
System.out.println(
    dtf.format(Instant.parse("2022-05-17T00:00:00.00Z"))
);
```

Comment: One potential unexpected nuance of WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR (depends what OP is doing): 53 is a valid value. That might be congruent with what he's already doing, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

## Definition of “week” varies by locale

The [Answer by Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72435981/642706) is correct. There are several definitions of a week, and they vary by locale.

You asked:

> Still, the question is why pattern ww is Locale specific?

Because the definition of *week* is cultural.

Even limiting our scope to the seven-day week currently common in the West, which of those seven days is first day of the week? Monday is common in Europe , while the US  uses Sunday. Should week # 1 start with the first occurrence of that first day of week? Or should the week start with January 1?

## ISO 8601 standard

If you want consistency, consider using the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) week definition:

- Monday is first day of week, Sunday last.
- Week # 1 contains the first Thursday of the calendar year.
- A week-based year has either 52 or 53 complete 7-day weeks.
- The first and last week may have zero or more days from the previous/next Calendar year, respectively.

The standard format is four-digit year, hyphen, a `W`, and two digits for week number. The standard formats are cleverly designed to avoid ambiguity, be easily parsed by machine, and be understandable by humans across cultures.

To work with ISO 8601 weeks, I suggest adding the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project for its [`YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class.

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.parse( "2022-W19" ) ;
String output = yw.toString() ;
```

Get year-week by date.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2022-05-10" ) ;
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.from( ld ) ;
```

Get year-week from a moment in UTC represented by text in standard ISO 8601 format. The `Z` on the end seen below means an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds, and is pronounced “Zulu”.

```
String input = "2022-05-10T00:00:00.00Z" ; 
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.at( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.from( odt ) ;
```